# Exact Cardinality for Elasticsearch documents

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I want to know about the algorithm (hyperloglog++) elasticsearch uses for unique counts.

Can setting a precision threshold to a particular value give me an exact unique count up to that threshold, disregarding the memory constraints?

Does the algorithm use linear counter up to the precision threshold and switch to the hyperloglog counter after that?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it uses linear counting in a hash table up to the precision threshold. You can also see that in the [relevant code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/b08cffad48ed3833e69611fb5bfbc9bb85c2f72b/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/metrics/HyperLogLogPlusPlus.java#L43-L49).

But also remember that the default precision threshold is 3,000 and you can set it up to 40,000 at most. Setting a higher value will actually cap it at 40,000. So no exact results for higher cardinalities.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So, I will get the exact count = threshold upto 40,000 right?

Comment: Yes, if you set the precision threshold to that. Otherwise up to 3,000 by default.

Comment: OK, but the doco doesn't promise that. So theoretically, the behaviour could change at any time. "precision_threshold...below which counts are expected to be close to accurate." https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html

Comment: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/default-precision-of-cardinality-aggregation/51665/2 has a better description from the colleague who wrote the code. While it's hard to predict changes, I would assume those to only happen in a major version, but you would have to check the release notes (which you shouldn't do in any case with a major release )